# Is opening/closing of JDBC connection instead of maintaining it, desirable for my application?

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

Every 30 seconds my server gets GPS coordinates of every user connected. Every time I receive these coordinates, I have to store/update these in a MySQL table. The clients connect to the server using web sockets, so a new object and a thread are created for every connection. So basically, every client has a JDBC connection open to the database. My question is-

1. Should I close the JDBC connection every time the server updates the values and open it after 30 seconds when it receives the next values(**to save memory space**)?

   Or
2. Should I leave the JDBC connection open(I've heard **JDBC open/close are expensive operations**)?

Comment: 2. Keep them open. And 1. Use a Connection Pool. Finally, 3. Make sure you return the connection to the pool.

Comment: Better use Hibernate to avoid such issues of frequent opening and closing of connections. Because Hibernate internally create Pooling of objects. And the major advantage of using Hibernate is it's first and second level cache. By using this you can easily maintain all your database transactions in one connection.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch 'Use a connection pool' and 'return them to the pool' both contradict 'keep them open'. You need to clear up this confusion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's depend on the architecture of your server side codes and the way you `insert`/`update` your tables:

- Do you maintain creating transactions or not? Or your connection is `AutoCommit=true`?
- Are you doing a number of operations in a batch or doing single operations using different connections?

The most efficient and publicly used way is creating a connection pool with a rational number of initial connections. This helps with the expensive operation of creating connections. So you are doing this operation (creating connection pool) only once when your server is started.

Then in your codes you should refactor creating connections and replace it with getting a connection from the pool. Then after you used the connection for the CRUD operations, you should close it to make sure you are returning it to the pool.

However in small applications with limited number of connections it doesn't matter how you open/close connections. But having a managed connection pool is a very important step in designing and implementing a large enterprise application.

You can implement your own way of connection pooling using these examples:

[How to set up a MySQL connection pool in Java](http://www.rndblog.com/how-to-set-up-a-mysql-connection-pool-in-java/)

[Java Database Connection Pooling](http://www.snaq.net/java/DBPool/)

Also if your server application is managed and run by a web server like tomcat you can let the tomcat handle creating and managing the connection pool for you. You should just define a `datasource` in tomcat. See this tutorial:

[Connection Pooling in a Java Web Application with Tomcat](https://dzone.com/articles/connection-pooling-tomcat-nb)

Hope this would be helpful.

Comment: After using a connection from a connection pool **you should close it**, because that is what returns the connection to the pool. I have edited your answer to reflect that.

Answer (score 1):

With a huge amount of users connect to your system, both of opening/closing and maintaining connections are expensive and require much memory. Each connection per user is redundant. I think you should looking for a connection pool. You can check this:
http://people.apache.org/~fhanik/jdbc-pool/jdbc-pool.html